# Cannot figure a simple mysql query out

Tags: mysql, sql, logic

I feel very very stupid now because I have a problem and cannot seem to figure it out.

Very simple MySQL table with 2 columns :

```
ID1   |    ID2
 1    |     1
 1    |     2
 2    |     1
```

Don't know very good how to explain the conditions : I want to select the value 1 from the column ID1 because it has connections with the values 1 AND 2 from ID2.

It's somewhat the opposite of IN.

If I make 
`SELECT ID1 FROM X WHERE ID2 IN (1,2)` I recieve both 1 and 2 because it is a reunion. I want an intersection, something like `SELECT ID1 FROM X WHERE ID2 IN BOTH 1 AND 2`.

I am fairly sure it has something to do with grouping.

1 solution is to make

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT ID1, GROUP_COCAT(ID2) y
FROM X
GROUP BY ID1)t
WHERE t.y = '1,2'
```

but this is NOT ok because I do not know the order ( 1,2 or 2,1 ) and I can have more values.

Hopefully this is clear enough, I am very tired.

Comment: ID2 contains only 1 and 2 ?

Comment: this is just a small example, it will contain many more values. For ex it can contain 1,2,3,4 and if I search for 1,2 I want to recieve it as good result.

Comment: Could you make this question any more obscure? That said, I suspect that you're looking for the following... SELECT a.* FROM a WHERE a.y IN (1,2) GROUP BY a.x HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;

Comment: @Strawberry No, no modifications needed, my bad. Yes that was the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TEMP t
WHERE t.id2 IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY t.id1 HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

OR

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TEMP t
WHERE t.id2 IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
GROUP BY t.id1 HAVING COUNT(*) = 4
```

Comment: Yes, I got it, like Strawberry and you said, don't know how I never touth of that... WIll accept the answer in 10 minutes